# (SonarQube) LinkedHashMap and S1640 (tells you to use an EnumMap)

Tags: java, enums, sonarqube, sonarlint

I might miss something, but declaring a LinkedHashmap:

```
private final LinkedHashMap<anEnum, anInteger> linkedHashMap;
```

and later:

```
linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<anEnum, anInteger>();
```

results in:

> "Maps with keys that are enum values should be replaced with EnumMap" 
>   (SQUID: 1640)

Since there is no "LinkedEnumMap", this declaration should be ignored.

Comment: Why dont you check their bug database? That part of your question doesnt make much sense ...

Answer (score 5):

Thing is: using **EnumMap** is good practice, therefore SonarQube tells you to do so.

But you explicitly choose to use a *LinkedHashMap* - which keeps track of insertion order.

So that message could be interpreted as:

- when you only care about mapping enums, use EnumMap
- when you need to map enums and care about insertion order, you have to stay with the ordinary LinkedHashMap

In other words: keep in mind that such tools are just *tools*. They provide messages to *help* you making informed decisions. When you decided that your current implementation is fine - then don't change your code, just because some tool puts up such "advise".

Comment: Very right. For some people Sonar is a bible. But in fact it isn't . It is a very good tool but we should always balance the issue that is produces as it may be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

> A specialized Map implementation for use with enum type keys. All of
>   the keys in an enum map must come from a single enum type that is
>   specified, explicitly or implicitly, when the map is created. Enum
>   maps are represented internally as arrays. This representation is
>   extremely compact and efficient.

[--Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html)

Basically it's not a bug, it's a good recommendation. Each `Enum` has it's order which comes from the order of declaration. You can see it in an array which is returned by `values()`.

`EnumMap` keeps that order and actually stores the values in an array.

On the other hand, you can decide which collection is better for your purpose. I believe that combining `EnumMap` and a `List` might be interesting you, but remember that Sonar is just a hint. You can reconfigure your Sonar and tell it not to indicate this case.

Comment: I agree for using EnumMaps, but my list is pre-sorted. It should keep the sorting state. I need the LinkedHashMap. I think recommending something impossible (since there is no LinkedEnumMap) is... a bug.

Comment: You won't miss any performance. You can hold sorted list of enums but at the same time perform mapping on EnumMap. Access to EnumMap is very efficient.

Comment: The purpose of a LinkedHashMap is that it can maintain order of keys in either insertion or access order. It can also function as an LRU cache. An EnumMap always maintains its keys in their natural order, so I would think an EnumMap would rarely if ever be a possible replacement for a LinkedHashMap

Comment: @EvanDarke it won't replace, but it might be used in combination with a List for speeding up the process of - in this case - counting elements.

Comment: Just because EnumMaps exist doesn't mean that they need to be used all the time. When you have two objects that "relate", you have to ensure that they are updated together for example. This adds complexity.

Comment: @GhostCat I agree.